# catch non window event with alpinejs

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

with alpinejs I can easily catch custom window events.

markup

```
<div x-data="map_data" @mapupdate.window="updateTodos">

...
```

js

```
const sendEvent = (name, payload) => {
    var evt = new CustomEvent(name, {detail: payload});
    window.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
sendEvent("mapupdate", {"okay":"roger"})
```

Let's say I don't want to create a window event but catch a "local" event coming from leaflet. This is how I can normally catch the event:

```
map.on('zoomend', function() {
    console.log("end");
});
```

Is it possible to instead dispatching a custom event again to directly catch the leaflet event with alpinejs?

```
<div x-data="map_data" @zoomend.map="updateTodos">
```

Comment: You can use x-init="" to use vanilla js to listen to the 'zoomend' and call the 'updateTodos', but I don't know a way to listen using only alpinejs

Comment: So you mean to move the map.on into x-init right?

Comment: Oh yes, `<div x-init="map.on('zoomend', function() { $store.shop.toggle() })">` this is definitely a step forward

Comment: Great, if you get stuck just keep me informed :)